# Enigmail pgp key in Libre office

Tags: libreoffice, thunderbird, pgp, enigmail

sorry if this was already answered, but I couldn't find the right answer on my own.

I am using Enigmail in Thunderbird and created a pgp key (priv and pub) for myself in Enigmail. Now I want to sign documents created in Libre Office. 
My pgp key pair appears in Seahorse, but doesn't appear in Seahorse opened by Libre Office, because they are not marked as "personal" (and Libreoffice only signs documents with keys marked as personal?).

Do I have to export it from Enigmail and reimport it to Seahorse? Then I would have them two times, wouldn't I?

**How can I use my pgp key created in Enigmail for signing documents in Libre Office?**

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Good question. I am analyzing the same. I join the thread.